# JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME in mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

JAVA_HOME is not set currently. Please set JAVA_HOME. I want to run appium programs but its throwing this weird error
[image]

Even  java_home path not displaying in terminal. Currently displaying blank
[image: JAVA_HOME showing empty]

**My bash profile**
[image]

JAVA VERSION Is also getting displayed
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following command:

- vim .bash_profile (do you see **export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)**  under the file) ?

If not then you need to add it there.

If already added then run source .bash_profile, it reloads the file. And the path is set.

Comment: restarted my system. still echo $JAVA_HOME is displaying blank

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

Comment: run source .bash_profile and then try  echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: yes. after running source .bash_profile and then trying echo $JAVA_HOME displaying proper result.. but  do i have to run everytime?

Comment: nope, it was to reload the bash_profile file after the changes made. It is a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first bash line is incorrect.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Should be:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Comment: you need to restart the terminal, close it and open a new one